# Error while running command of gradlew signingreport

Tags: android, flutter

Hey I am new in Flutter App Development.
when i use ./gradlew signingReport command i am facing this issue how can i solve this.
I tried ./gradlew clean command to solve this but i can't.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vetnc.png)

Please help me to solve this issue.